# ClassNotFound W/ Spring using Eclipse Tomcat Maven M2Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring, tomcat, maven, m2eclipse

Sorry I am new to this stack overflow stuff so pardon the long error message at the bottom.

I am trying to deploy a project called BroadLeaf to a Tomcat 7 server using eclipse. I have installed M2Eclipse/WTP Integration. I run a maven configuration (through eclipse) with clean package as the goals. Then I do a refresh and try to start the server, however, it fails.

UPDATE: I am trying to deploy the project found here... https://broadleaf.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/broadleaf/trunk/BroadleafCommerce/site/BroadleafCommerceDemo/pom.xml

Any ideas?

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener
>         at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1664)
>         at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1509)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:406)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:388)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:117)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4268)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4771)
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:138)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:990)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:772)
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:138)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:990)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:275)
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:138)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:424)
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:138)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:648)
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:138)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:576)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:415)
>     Sep 27, 2011 8:41:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
>     SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.broadleafcommerce.profile.web.extensibility.MergeContextLoaderListener
>     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.broadleafcommerce.profile.web.extensibility.MergeContextLoaderListener
>         at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1664)
>         at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1509)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:406)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:388)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:117)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4268)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4771)
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:138)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:990)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:772)
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:138)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:990)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:275)
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:138)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:424)
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:138)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:648)
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:138)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:576)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:415)
>     Sep 27, 2011 8:41:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
>     SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
>     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
>         at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1664)
>         at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1509)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:406)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:388)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:117)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4268)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4771)
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:138)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:990)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:772)
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:138)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:990)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:275)
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:138)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:424)
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:138)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:648)
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:138)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:576)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:415)
>     Sep 27, 2011 8:41:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
>     SEVERE: Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
>     Sep 27, 2011 8:41:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
>     SEVERE: Error listenerStart
>     Sep 27, 2011 8:41:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
>     SEVERE: Context [/broadleaf] startup failed due to previous errors

Comment: Can you check if the  org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener is there in any of the jars. This gets specified in an XML file - so even if the class is missing you won't get compiler errors.

Comment: Good question, the dependencies are grabbed by Maven and added to a ./target/<projectName>/WEB-INF/lib folder. This means they are all located there once it is created. I believe m2Eclipse extension for WTP should handle pointing to this folder, however, it is either not working or I am missing a setting somewhere.

Comment: Want to let folks know that since this post Broadleaf Commerce has moved to GitHub.    Docs are available on the project website at http://www.broadleafcommerce.org under getting started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be with WTP not integrating properly with the maven dependancies. Not the best solution I fixed the issue by....

1. in eclipse right click on the project and go to properties
2. Go to deployment assembly
3. click add
4. Select Java Build path entries
5. select all the M2_HOME entries.
6. Clean build and deploy project DO NOT USE THE M2ECLIPSE PLUGIN WITH ECLIPSE:ECLIPSE!
7. Should get you around the error.

Anyone know the real solution?

UPDATE: Also the next time I imported WTP seemed to vibe with Maven, so maybe delete and reimport your project after installing the plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the pom files in broadleaf [source repository](https://broadleaf.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/broadleaf/trunk/BroadleafCommerce/), it looks like none of them build a `web` application (`war` artifact).  This is required for the `m2eclipse/wtp` integration to work correctly.

If this is not the case, please edit the question specifying the specific broadleaf sub project you are trying to deploy in tomcat.

Comment: You know I didn't even check that, I guess I just assumed they had it configured. So I will do some googling but that would be the maven-war-plugin correct?

Comment: Since you sound like you have experience in Broadleaf, am I right in assuming that I need to deploy the demo site? I know I can get it working via ant jetty-demo (or some such) but I am trying to deploy to a tomcat server and I assumed I could just use the war created by the mvn clean package command. Should I be using the launcher project instead?

Comment: Just checked and it does build the war... The pom I originally sent was the root pom, the one for the project is available here...https://broadleaf.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/broadleaf/trunk/BroadleafCommerce/site/BroadleafCommerceDemo/pom.xml